# problem with RODBC installation in Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu

I have a problem with some missing headers when trying to install RODBC in R on my linux. 
Can anyone help me with this issue?

```
> install.packages("RODBC")

Installing package(s) into ‘/home/administrator/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.12’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

trying URL 'http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/src/contrib/RODBC_1.3-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1108358 bytes (1.1 Mb)

opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 1.1 Mb

* installing *source* package ‘RODBC’ ...
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking sql.h usability... no
checking sql.h presence... no
checking for sql.h... no
checking sqlext.h usability... no
checking sqlext.h presence... no
checking for sqlext.h... no
configure: error: "ODBC headers sql.h and sqlext.h not found"
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RODBC’
* removing ‘/home/administrator/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.12/RODBC’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'RODBC' had non-zero exit status

The downloaded packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpqfNYpD/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Do suo apt-get install unixODBC*
https://github.com/zozlak/RODBCext/issues/2

Comment: Little bit newer thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107461/problem-with-rodbc-installation-in-ubuntu-with-r-3-5-1).

Answer (score 33):

As Dirk said in the comments, if you have already installed `r-cran-rodbc`, there is no need to run `install.packages()` from within R. `library(RODBC)` should load the package.

More generally, when you see errors regarding headers, it is because a required development library is not installed.  The solution is to search the web using the names of the missing header files (*e.g.* google for `sqlext.h ubuntu`), to identify the required package.  In this case, you need `libiodbc2-dev`. So:

```
sudo apt-get install libiodbc2-dev
```

Then the install within R should work.

Comment: FWIW the r-cran-binary is actually built against the *other* ODBC library in Debian / Ubuntu:  unixodbc-dev.

Comment: Do I have to do anything with ODBC driver?

Comment: Thanks for clarification Dirk; so "sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev" is an alternative.

Comment: I followed sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev and now RODBC is installed and load perfectly in R but when I try to connect to MySQL it says Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=10.134.5.62;Database=copy_number;User=root;Password=xxxx;Option=3;") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
2: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=10.134.5.62;Database=copy_number;User=root;Password=xxxx;Option=3;") :
  ODBC connection failed

Comment: How do I configure the ODBC driver ?

Comment: That's a separate question. But don't ask it: now is the time to go away and read some documentation, tutorials and mailing lists. Then come back with a specific query if you are still stuck.

Answer (score 14):

After attempting to install packages from all the solutions on this site and others, I was successful in building the `RODBC` package using:

`sudo apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev`

I also installed:

- libiodbc2-dev
- libmyodbc
- odbc-postgresql

Comment: This is the one you want if you're trying to install the ruby-odbc gem but are getting errors on debian/ubuntu.

Answer (score 12):

Do you really need to build from source?  Why don't you use the binary package?

So maybe try this instead:

```
  sudo apt-get install r-cran-rodbc
```

or use any of the GUI frontends to the package management system.

Comment: ...or follow [these instructions](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html) in general...

Comment: The r-cran-rodbc package is actually on the Ubuntu repos, and not on the CRAN ones.  But that README is still gold.

Comment: I already did this and it said....                                Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
r-cran-rodbc is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
BUT if I try installing the package in R it says the same error

Comment: So it is installed. So why do you want to install a second copy outside of the package management system?

Comment: Remember it still says..                                           checking sql.h usability... no
checking sql.h presence... no
checking for sql.h... no
checking sqlext.h usability... no
checking sqlext.h presence... no
checking for sqlext.h... no
configure: error: "ODBC headers sql.h and sqlext.h not found"
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RODBC’
* removing ‘/home/administrator/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.12/RODBC’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'RODBC' had non-zero exit status ...

Comment: When is try to access it using                               channel <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=10.134.5.62;Database=copy_number;User=root;Password=xxxx;Option=3;")
Warning messages:
[RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
2: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=10.134.5.62;Database=copy_number;User=root;Password=xxxx;Option=3;") :
  ODBC connection failed

Comment: You need to call `library(RODBC)` before you can use it.

Comment: I did after that only I tried accessing the db

Comment: I fear you are a tad confused between *installing* RODBC (which is not an issue as we have now found out--you have the binary package and can load it) and *using and configuring RODBC* which is a different ballgame.  Look for previous questions here and on the lists.  Also, if your backend is indeed MySQL then you could use RMySQL instead which may well be faster.

Comment: Is it about installing ODBC driver?

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, I had the same problem ("ODBC headers sql.h and sqlext.h not found") on OS X, and fixed it by installing unixodbc (`brew install unixodbc`)

Comment: This does not seem to be relevant to the original question in any way. Explaining how uninstalling something with HomeBrew on a OS/X system hardly helps the person struggling with Ubuntu, don't you think? Please take a minute to consider how you could improve your answer and address the problem described in the question.

Comment: **os x** ? how does installing on osx solve problem of ubuntu

Comment: unixodbc exists also for Ubuntu.

Comment: I tried it just now, but R said that unixodbc is not available for R version 3.3.1, which is what's running on the server. It seems to be needing an upgrade ;)

Answer (score 1):

RODBC depends on R (>= 3.0.0 
(see for example https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/RODBC.pdf)

Your local package library...

```
Installing package(s) into '/home/administrator/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.12'
```

... suggests that you may have an older version of R installed (2.12). If this is the case, try upgrading to a recent version of R.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue and additionally used `conda` environment with only R 4.0.3 installed.
Nothing from the above helped.
Then in desperation I've run in the termial: 
`conda install r-odbc` 
and it worked! After this, in R 
`install.packages("RODBC")` 
Problem solved!
Notice though that I tried out all the advices above, so some of the `sudo apt-get ...` commands mentioned here could have been relevant - hard to say now.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. For me the solution was  I was missing some [Ubuntu dependencies](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/r-cran-rodbc) such as

- [unixodbc (>= 2.2.11)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/unixodbc)
- [libmyodbc](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libmyodbc)
- [odbc-postgresql](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/odbc-postgresql)

It's noteworthy that `install.packages("RODBC", dependencies=TRUE)` does *not* pick up these packages. They lie outside `R` itself.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using libiodbc, and the installer still can't find it, you can do something like the following, making sure to point to the correct libiodbc directory:

```
install.packages("RODBC", configure.args="--with-odbc-include=/usr/include/libiodbc")
```